# How do I write a custom sorter to sort my springdoc swagger tags by name in the UI?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

I am using springdoc-openapi with the latest version (1.3.0). Now I would like **sort my tags in the UI by "name"** property.

I know about the "springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter" configuration and that I can use a custom sorter function. But I cannot find examples how the function should look like.

I tried the following which does not seem to work:

springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=(a, b) => a.get("name").localeCompare(b.get("name"))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, you can sort tags alphabetically:

- https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-sort-endpoints-alphabetically

You can have control on the tags order, using OpenApiCustomiser and define your own Comparator:

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser sortTagsAlphabetically() {
    return openApi -> openApi.setTags(openApi.getTags()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(tag -> StringUtils.stripAccents(tag.getName())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: Since Springdoc sort tags, field value alphabetically, how can we disable this ?

Answer (score 18):

With reference from [@brianbro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61541619/870834), as suggested at https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-sort-endpoints-alphabetically

I added

`@Tag(name="1. Admin endpoints")`

`@Tag(name = "2. Everyone's enpoints!")`

and below prop to application.yml :

`springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha`

And can see them sorted according to numbering on my swagger UI.

Comment: Thanks. To add that this works with both numbers and letters. The above example might be confusing for some people that the tags are prefixed with numbers. Those tags without the numbers will have the same order because Admin... < Everyone...

Answer (score 3):

For sorting schemas , paths and tags in OpenApi.

```
    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser() {
        return openApi -> {
            Map<String, Schema> schemas = openApi.getComponents().getSchemas();
            openApi.getComponents().setSchemas(new TreeMap<>(schemas));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser sortPathsAndTagsAlphabetically() {
        return openApi -> {
            Map<String, PathItem> paths = openApi.getPaths();
            Paths sortedPaths = new Paths();
            TreeMap<String, PathItem> sortedTree = new TreeMap<String, PathItem>(paths);

            Set<Map.Entry<String, PathItem>> pathItems = sortedTree.entrySet();
            Map<String, Map.Entry<String, PathItem>> distinctTagMap = new TreeMap<String, Map.Entry<String, PathItem>>();
            for ( Map.Entry<String, PathItem> entry:pathItems) {
                PathItem pathItem = entry.getValue();
                Operation getOp = pathItem.getGet();
                if(getOp != null) {
                    String tag = getOp.getTags().get(0);
                    if (!distinctTagMap.containsKey(tag)) {
                        distinctTagMap.put(tag, entry);
                    }
                }
                Operation postOp = pathItem.getPost();
                if(postOp != null){
                    String tag1 = postOp.getTags().get(0);
                    if(!distinctTagMap.containsKey(tag1)){
                        distinctTagMap.put(tag1,entry);
                    }
                }

                Operation putOp = pathItem.getPut();
                if(putOp != null) {
                    String tag2 = putOp.getTags().get(0);
                    if (!distinctTagMap.containsKey(tag2)) {
                        distinctTagMap.put(tag2, entry);
                    }
                }
            }

            LinkedHashMap<String, PathItem> customOrderMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, PathItem>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, PathItem> entry: distinctTagMap.values()) {
                customOrderMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            for(Map.Entry<String, PathItem> entry : sortedTree.entrySet()) {
                customOrderMap.putIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            sortedPaths.putAll(customOrderMap);
            openApi.setPaths(sortedPaths);

        };
    }
```

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't sort PathItems, belonging to the same path, but with multiple methods, like both put and delete.