# How to sort endpoint in reverse order using springdoc-openapi

Tags: java, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using spring doc-open API with version (1.2.32). Now I would like to sort my endpoints in UI by its HTTP method (reverse order) and I am not using any tags on my endpoint method.

If I have 4 endpoint post, get, put, delete
then I want to display methods Put, post, get, delete

I tried the following, which does not seem to work:

> springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=(method and alpha)

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69461862/870834

Answer (score 4):

This is the working properties:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
```

Make sure you are using the last stable version.
As per December 2020; it's 1.5.0.