# How to sort the @PathVariable enum value on Swagger-ui SpringDoc open ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a GET method in Controller that takes as one of a parameters (@PathVariable) an Enum. This Enum has several values and when it is being generated by Swagger/OpenApi, in the Swagger UI when testing/try out the endpoint, list of possible parameter values coming from Enum, is displayed. However it is being displayed in the order in which values are typed in Enum. I would like to order the list alphabetically, to be displayed in Swagger UI.
I cannot simply sort the Enum as it is coming from external library.

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/status/{enumStatus}/validate")
public ResponseEntity<RootElement> getMethod(@PathVariable("id") final String id, @PathVariable("status") final StatusEnum enumStatus) {
        return myRestService.validate(id, enumStatus);
    }

    private enum StatusEnum {
        B_STATUS, A_STATUS, NO_STATUS, CC_STATUS
    }
```

I was hoping for something similar but I was not able to get specific PathVariable:
[How do I write a custom sorter to sort my springdoc swagger tags by name in the UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810048/how-do-i-write-a-custom-sorter-to-sort-my-springdoc-swagger-tags-by-name-in-the)

I don't know if this sorting is possible at all..

Answer (score 0):

Swagger UI does not have an option to sort enums.

One possible solution is to fork the [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/) repository, modify the code responsible for displaying enums (at least [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/main/src/core/components/layout-utils.jsx#L192-L203) and [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/main/src/core/components/parameter-row.jsx#L295-L298), possibly elsewhere), rebuild it, and use your custom fork in your app.